# How to pass a value inside an observable with getObject function (aws / S3) in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, aws-sdk

I try to learn observable programming with Angular (4.4.6):

Like to do: get json file from AWS / S3 Storage, save content (string), return the content in the observable.

employee.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

...  

getNotice (userid): Observable<String> {

    const params = {
       Bucket: 'data.feedback.domain.de',
       Key: 'employees/' + userid + '/notice/notice.json'
    };

    var objectData = '';

    this.bucket.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Successfully get file: notice.json:', data.Body.toString());
      objectData = data.Body.toString();
    });
    console.log('objectData:', objectData);
    return Observable.of(objectData);

}
...
```

In the getObject function I receive the file notice.json and in the console I see the string saved in notice.json.

But saving the data with *objectData = data.Body.toString()* doesn't work.

Any hint, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why you decide what objectData is empty? Do you try paste debugger after `objectData = data.Body.toString();` line and check what saves in this variable?

Comment: Yes, I did. If I save the result in an array, it is working: 
`const objectData = new Array<Notice>();
...
objectData.push( new Notice(data.Body.toString()) );`

Answer (score 1):

it's looks like async error, you need paste data to observable from inside of your callback function

```
import { create } from 'rxjs';

...

getNotice (userid): Observable<String> {

    const params = {
       Bucket: 'data.feedback.domain.de',
       Key: 'employees/' + userid + '/notice/notice.json'
    };

    var objectData = '';

    return create(observer => { 
      this.bucket.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + err);
          observer.error(err);
        }
        console.log('Successfully get file: notice.json:', data.Body.toString());
        objectData = data.Body.toString();
        observer.next(objectData);
    });

}
```

Comment: sorry for my English

Comment: more about observable creation you can find here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/

Answer (score 0):

```
    var objectData = '';
// Following is an asychronous/non-blocking code so callback called after the response is returned from S3 but execution goes to next line immediately.
this.bucket.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Successfully get file: notice.json:', data.Body.toString());
  objectData = data.Body.toString();
});
// Following will be executed even before the S3 returns the response so you must see following console log before console.log('Successfully get file: notice.json:', data.Body.toString());
console.log('objectData:', objectData);
return Observable.of(objectData);
```

I have put the answer as inline comments in the code basically s3 call is asynchronous/non-blocking so but you have written assuming it is a blocking code.

Comment: Yes, thank you. In the callback function I get the right content of the notice.json.  I didn't find a tutorial or example how I can fix it.

Comment: I found a hint that I should work like this:

`var request = this.bucket.getObject(params);
request.on('success', function(response) {
   console.log('Successfully get file: notice.json:', response);
   return response;
});
request.send();`

That's ok and gives also the content. The code is inside a function in a service.
To give the answer to the caller I can work with an observable.